# if condition returning different values on different environments

Tags: java, tomcat, myeclipse

'i am having 3 string variables.'

```
String x, y, z;

after db call variables are set to

x=    ; (blank)
y=null;
z=null;

after ternary condition

x=  ; (blank) 
y=no_value;
z=no_value;

then followed by if condition

 if(!x.equals("no_value"))
{
print 1st;
return;
}

if((y.equals("no_value") && (z.equals("no_value"))
{
print 2nd;
return;
}
```

'In my eclipse on windows OS with Tomcat it is working fine (checked on 2 systems) executing the 2nd if condition.

But after deploying to the application server (IBM web sphere on Solaris OS) it is executing the 1st if condition. (also checked on two different servers)

I guess its because of the other work all ready deployed on to the server(my work is a addition to existing application).

But what really wonders me is that as i am sure and also cross checked the inputs before the if conditions and sure of the variables being same on both environments. But how can one get two different outputs with same inputs & same logic ?'

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on with this pseudocode. It would be much easier if you could show some *genuine* code, ideally written *just* to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Based on what I could glimpse from your description, **both** `if` conditions should evaluate to `true` and produce printouts.

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet yes i agree with you.But this is the skeleton of the problem. With input variables and couple of if conditions. i will try to give the original code asap.Thanks for the reply

Comment: @jitendrak: We don't need the original code - we need code which is *valid Java code* and which you've seen demonstrate the problem on the relevant systems, but which has everything extraneous removed. This is part of what you should be doing to diagnose the problem in the first place - and it'll be *much* easier to help you once it's posted.

Comment: oops, i meant to say code which can represent the original problem.

Comment: PM, the first if condition clause contains a return statement, so, if it is executed, the second if condition won't be tested.